# Switch MultiSite main site with another (multilingual sites) - with subfolder - no subdomain

Tags: multisite

I have a WordPress Multisite with two blogs / sites. The main site is English and the second one is German.

| Site | URL |
| --- | --- |
| Current Main Site: English | example.org |
| German Site | example.org/de |

How can I switch these sites (with all settings and content)? The German site should become the primary one and the English one will not be used.

| Site | URL |
| --- | --- |
| New Main Site: German | example.org |
| English Site | example.org/en |

I already read [this about "Switching primary site in WordPress Multisite"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232038/switching-primary-site-in-wordpress-multisite/235578) but I'm not sure if it's still up to date and if it's the solution for my purpose.